# Write Data to BigQuery table using load_table_from_dataframe method ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to read the data from Cloud storage and write the data into BigQuery table. Used Pandas library for reading the data from GCS and to write the data used client.load_table_from_dataframe method. I am executing this code as python operator in Google cloud composer. Got below error when i execute the code.

```
[2020-06-23 17:09:36,119] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'@-@{"workflow": "DataTransformationSample1", "task-id": "dag_init", "execution-date": "2020-06-23T17:03:42.202219+00:00"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 930, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/DataTransformationSample1.py", line 225, in dag_initialization
    destination=table_id, job_config=job_config)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 968, in load_table_from_dataframe
    job_config=job_config,
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 887, in load_table_from_file
    job_resource = load_job._build_resource()
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line 1379, in _build_resource
    self.destination.to_api_repr())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'
[2020-06-23 17:09:36,122] {base_task_runner.py:115} INFO - Job 202544: Subtask dag_init [2020-06-23 17:09:36,119] {taskinstance.py:1059} ERROR - 'str' object has no attribute 'to_api_repr'@-@{"workflow": "DataTransformationSample1", "task-id": "dag_init", "execution-date": "2020-06-23T17:03:42.202219+00:00"}
```

Below code i used,

```
client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = 'project.dataset.table'

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="Code", field_type="STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
        bigquery.SchemaField(name="Value", field_type="STRING", mode="NULLABLE")
    ]
job_config.create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED"
job_config.write_disposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE"

load_result = client.load_table_from_dataframe(dataframe=concatenated_df,
                                               destination=table_id, job_config=job_config)
load_result.result()
```

Someone please help to solve this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically Panda consider string as object, but BigQuery doesn't know it. We need to explicitly convert the object to string using Panda in order to make it load the data to BQ table.

df[columnname] = df[columnname].astype(str)